# Haskell data type for hmatrix Vector and Matrix

Tags: haskell, graph, functional-programming, ghci

I am just starting out with Haskell, I have read up to the defining data types section of LYAH and am attempting to implement the Sum-Product algorithm for Belief Propagation. One of the rudimentary tasks is to define the Probabilistic Graphical Model.

As shown below, I have attempted to create a graph by tying the knot to represent the graph where each node represents a Gaussian distribution and has constant weight links(for now) to it's neighbours. However, when trying to define the Mean and Covariance types I am having some difficulty in specifying the types of the Matrix and Vector types, i.e. Float or Double.

```
module Graph(Graph) where

import Numeric.LinearAlgebra

data Mean = Mean Vector
data Covariance = Covariance Matrix
data Gaussian = Gaussian Mean Covariance

data Node = Node [Node] Gaussian
data Graph = Graph [Node]
```

In this simple example, what is the syntax to define Mean as a Vector of type Double and Covariance as a Matrix of type Double. Additionally, how would one generalise so that `Mean` and `Covariance` can be of type Float or Double?

I currently get the following from GHCi

```
Graph.hs:5:18: error:
    • Expecting one more argument to ‘Vector’
      Expected a type, but ‘Vector’ has kind ‘* -> *’
    • In the type ‘Vector’
      In the definition of data constructor ‘Mean’
      In the data declaration for ‘Mean’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I am using the hmatrix package as described [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vector` and `Matrix` are parameterised on the scalar type (so you can not only have matrices of floating-point “real numbers”, but also matrices of integers, complex numbers etc.). This is what GHC tells you by `‘Vector’ has kind ‘* -> *’`: by itself, `Vector` is not a type (types have kind `*`, aka `Type`). Rather it is a *type function* mapping types of kind `*` to types of kind `*`. Scalars like `Double` are already plain types, so you can just apply `Vector` to them.

```
GHCi> :kind Vector
Vector :: * -> *
GHCi> :k Double
Double :: *
GHCi> :k Vector Double
Vector Double :: *
```

Thus you need

```
newtype Mean = Mean (Vector Double)
newtype Covariance = Covariance (Matrix Double)
```

(`newtype` does the same thing as `data` here, but it's a bit more efficient because no extra box/pointer is needed).

Alternatively, you may use more meaningfully-typed vector spaces, e.g.

```
import Math.LinearMap.Category

newtype Mean v = Mean v
newtype Covariance v = Covariance (v +> DualVector v)
```

The advantage of this is that dimensions are checked at compile time, which prevents nasty runtime errors (and can in principle also improve performance, though frankly the `linearmap-category` library is not optimised at all yet).

You'd then also parameterise the other types over the vector space:

```
data Gaußian v = Gaußian (Mean v) (Covariance v)
data Node v = Node [Node v] (Gaussian v)
data Graph v = Graph [Node v]
```

Somewhat unrelated to your question: this knot-tying sure feels elegant, but it's not really a suitable way to represent a graph, because nodes can't be identity-checked. Any cycles in the graph lead to, for all distinguishable means, an infinite structure. In practice, you won't get around giving your nodes e.g. `Int` labels and keeping a separate structure for the edges.

Comment: What a fantastic answer; thank you! That has cleared a few things up for me. I did have some doubts about the knot tying and inadvertantly creating an infinite structure. The other way(keeping adjacency matrixes, etc) just seemed, inelegant.